# Get Data Attribute from the new HTML Element just added using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, attributes

Just added new element in my HTML code using jquery .html() but cannot get the data attribute from this new element.

Ilustration:

```
<div class="row" id="append">
  <div class="col-12" id="newElement">
    <button>Add new element</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 see-id">
    <button data-id="0.901065887770927">Check ID</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.see-id').click(function(){
      alert($(this).data('id'));
    })
    $('#newElement').click(function(){
      var rand = Math.random();
      $('#newElement').after('<div class="col-md-3 see-id"><button data-id="'+rand+'">Check ID</button></div>');
    })
  })
</script>
```

How to get data attribute from the new element just added using DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're adding new HTML to the document you need to [use event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to get at the data. Attach the listener to the parent element, in this case `.row`. But you also need to target the button, so your selector should be `.see-id button`.

Note: I've separated out the HTML so the query can work better. New buttons were being added before the previous ones in the `.row` div which could give misleading results when you clicked on them. In this example I use `append` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.row').on('click', '.see-id button', function () {
   const id = $(this).data('id');
   console.log(id);
  });

  $('#newElement').on('click', function () {
    const rand = Math.random();
    $('.row').append(`<div class="col-md-3 see-id"><button data-id="${rand}">Check ID</button></div>`);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newElement">
  <button>Add new element</button>
</div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. Very appreciated